# pandas groupby-apply gives weird result when there is only one group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below code (dataframe with 2 groups, a and b)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['a', 'a', 'b'], 'c2': [1, 2, 3], 'c3': [4, 5, 6]})

   c1  c2  c3
0   a   1   4
1   a   2   5
2   b   3   6

df.groupby('c1', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df[['c2', 'c3']].max(axis=1).rolling(2).mean())
```

gives a series

```
0    NaN
1    4.5
2    NaN
Name: c2, dtype: float64
```

and this is as expected.

But below code (dataframe with only one group, a)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['a', 'a', 'a'], 'c2': [1, 2, 3], 'c3': [4, 5, 6]})

   c1  c2  c3
0   a   1   4
1   a   2   5
2   a   3   6

df.groupby('c1', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df[['c2', 'c3']].max(axis=1).rolling(2).mean())
```

gives a dataframe, not a series

```
     0    1    2
c1              
a  NaN  4.5  5.5
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: depending on your pandas version, you can use the paramater `squeeze=True` that would give you the same structure than the example with 2 groups, but it is supposed to be depreciated starting version 1.1.0